# How would I yield an immutable.Map in Scala?

Tags: scala, dictionary, for-loop, immutability, yield

I have tried this but it does not work:

```
val map:Map[String,String] = for {
    tuple2 <- someList
  } yield tuple2._1 -> tuple2._2
```

How else would I convert a List of Tuple2s into a Map?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My First try is this:

```
scala> val country2capitalList = List("England" -> "London", "Germany" -> "Berlin")
country2capitalList: List[(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)] = List((England,London), (Germany,Berlin))

scala> val country2capitalMap = country2capital.groupBy(e => e._1).map(e => (e._1, e._2(0)._2))
country2capitalMap: scala.collection.Map[java.lang.String,java.lang.String] = Map(England -> London, Germany -> Berlin)
```

But here is the best solution:

```
scala> val betterConversion = Map(country2capitalList:_*)
betterConversion: scala.collection.immutable.Map[java.lang.String,java.lang.String] = Map(England -> London, Germany -> Berlin)
```

The `:_*` is needed to give the compiler a hint to use the list as a varargs argument. Otherwise it will give you:

```
scala> Map(country2capitalList)
<console>:6: error: type mismatch;
 found   : List[(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)]
 required: (?, ?)
       Map(country2capitalList)
           ^
```

From Scala 2.8 on you can use `toMap`:

```
scala> val someList = List((1, "one"), (2, "two"))   
someList: List[(Int, java.lang.String)] = List((1,one), (2,two))

scala> someList.toMap
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,java.lang.String] = Map((1,one), (2,two))
```

Answer (score 14):

It couldn't be simpler:

```
Map(listOf2Tuples: _*)
```

using the [`apply`](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/api/scala/collection/immutable/Map$object.html#apply%28%28A%2CB%29*%29) method in `Map` companion object.

Comment: Only works if `listOf2Tuples` is explicit and not a variable/val

Comment: until `toMap` came along (scala 2.8)

Comment: Well, this reply was before 2.8 final :)

Answer (score 9):

In 2.8, you can use the `toMap` method:

```
scala> val someList = List((1, "one"), (2, "two"))   
someList: List[(Int, java.lang.String)] = List((1,one), (2,two))

scala> someList.toMap
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,java.lang.String] = Map((1,one), (2,two))
```

This will work for any collection of pairs.  Note that the documentation has this to say about its duplicate policy:

> Duplicate keys will be overwritten by
>   later keys: if this is an unordered
>   collection, which key is in the
>   resulting map is undefined.

Answer (score 7):

In scala 2.8:

```
scala> import scala.collection.breakOut
import scala.collection.breakOut

scala> val ls = List("a","bb","ccc")
ls: List[java.lang.String] = List(a, bb, ccc)

scala> val map: Map[String,Int] = ls.map{ s => (s,s.length) }(breakOut)
map: Map[String,Int] = Map((a,1), (bb,2), (ccc,3))

scala> val map2: Map[String,Int] = ls.map{ s => (s,s.length) }.toMap
map2: Map[String,Int] = Map((a,1), (bb,2), (ccc,3))

scala>
```